# Find the values of $\,a$ if when divided by $\,x-a$, both $\,x-a$, both $\,x^3 +ax-5$ and $x^3 -x^2 +3x -3\,$ give the same remainder.

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

Find the values of 'a' if when divided by $x-a$, both $x-a$, both $x^3 +ax-5$ and $x^3 -x^2 +3x -3$ give the same remainder.

Could someone please hint me with this question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Put $x=a$ in the polynomials. They should be equal.

Comment: yep iv done that

Comment: got it thanks!!